# Colorizing text

Tags: bash

How can I show text in color with Bash?

- `a`: white text on brown background
- `b`: black text on yellow background

```
echo -e "bbb aaa bbb"
```

and

```
echo -e "aaa bbb aaa"
```

My result is not nice :-(

Comment: No time to write up an answer, but here is a hyperlink instead: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/037

Comment: @kojiro but what if I want 256 color goodness? While tput fails, this is easy to achieve with ANSI escape sequences, as [described here](http://bitmote.com/index.php?post/2012/11/19/Using-ANSI-Color-Codes-to-Colorize-Your-Bash-Prompt-on-Linux) (near the end).

Comment: @MichaelPlotke you can do whatever you want if you're just targeting specific terminals, but if you want to write portable code, you use capability tests, same as if you were writing cross-browser or compiler code.

Comment: And 16 colours are enough for terminals. Remember that ECMA (ANSI) didn't standardize the colours, so each terminal will show differently, and users now tend to customize own terminals, so you risk to optimize only for your specific computer (which it is good, and a use case of 256 colours, but not to be hardcoded). Consider accessibility and that often commands are used inside other commands, so colours may make parsing more difficult (so again: OK for you, but on programs which should be used by others, things are much more complex)

Answer (score 6):

```
# text
black='\e[0;30m'
white='\e[0;37m'
yellow='\e[0;33m'

# background
white_bg='\e[47m'

echo -e "${black}black test"
echo -e "${white_bg}white bg and black test"
echo -e "${yellow}yellow test"
```

Comment: Don't hardcode terminal escapes - use `tput` instead, to get the correct value (if any) for the actual terminal in use.

Answer (score 5):

You can provide some colors like these in your `~/.bashrc`

```
txtblk='\e[0;30m' # Black - Regular
txtred='\e[0;31m' # Red
txtgrn='\e[0;32m' # Green
txtylw='\e[0;33m' # Yellow
txtblu='\e[0;34m' # Blue
txtpur='\e[0;35m' # Purple
txtcyn='\e[0;36m' # Cyan
txtwht='\e[0;37m' # White
```

Afterwards you can use `echo`:

```
echo -e "${txtred}asd${txtwht}"
```

[Here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt#List_of_colors_for_prompt_and_Bash) you can find more colors.

Comment: Using that echo command just prints the code out and the text following it for me.

Comment: Don't hardcode terminal escapes - use `tput` instead, to get the correct value (if any) for the actual terminal in use.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how you do it with tput:

```
txtblk=$(tput setaf 0) # Black - Regular
txtred=$(tput setaf 1) # Red
txtgrn=$(tput setaf 2) # Green
txtylw=$(tput setaf 3) # Yellow
txtblu=$(tput setaf 4) # Blue
txtpur=$(tput setaf 5) # Purple
txtcyn=$(tput setaf 6) # Cyan
txtwht=$(tput setaf 7) # White
```

But the approach of saving it to `.bashrc` is not advisable, because it's a good practice to disable colors whenever the `-t test` fails.

So a better approach is to have a file with something like this:

```
[[ -t 1 ]] || export TERM=dumb
txtblk=$(tput setaf 0) # Black - Regular
txtred=$(tput setaf 1) # Red
txtgrn=$(tput setaf 2) # Green
txtylw=$(tput setaf 3) # Yellow
txtblu=$(tput setaf 4) # Blue
txtpur=$(tput setaf 5) # Purple
txtcyn=$(tput setaf 6) # Cyan
txtwht=$(tput setaf 7) # White
```

and source it whenever you need colors. `tput` will put zero-length strings on dumb terminals and whenever the stdout is not a terminal. So:

`./my-script` would print colors, but `./my-script | grep foo` won't send color codes to `grep`.

Edit: Colors have been fixed to represent the typical numbering of the colors as per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#8-bit

Note, it is possible to change the order of the colors for a specific terminal, but it is also ill-advised.

Answer (score 0):

I keep coming back here and then going off to find the colour codes. Leaving this one liner to dump all foreground and background colours on the terminal.

```
    fg='\e[38;5;';bg='\e[48;5;';for ix in {1..256}; do printf "fg \"%s\e[38;5;%sm%s\e[0mm\"\tbg \"%s\e[48;5;%sm%s\e[0mm\"\n" ${fg} ${ix} ${ix} ${bg} ${ix} ${ix}; done; printf "\e[0m"
```